# sql server query for order by specified date

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Id,Date,Name 
FROM people 
WHERE DATEPART(hh,Date) >= 7 
AND DATEPART(hh,Date) <= 8 
Order by DATEPART(ww,Date);
```

My database is SQL Server, and the thing is that "Date" are stored as a string type. If I execute that query it does not order properly.

What I want to do is, get each day's value for between 7am and 8 am. For example, I want to get 14th of June records for between 7am and 8am,  samething for 15th of june and so on....

Comment: Yes, but dd/MM/yyyy, yyyy-MM-dd, .. ?

Comment: You should post an example of how a date look on your table

Comment: dd/MM/yyyy hh-mm-ss    03-16-2001 07:00:20

Comment: @CoKoder - You are somewhat confused. You said the format was `dd/MM/yyyy hh-mm-ss` and posted `03-16-2001 07:00:20` as an example. But your example's format is `mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss`, so, wich one is it?

Comment: sorry, the example should have been 16-03-2001

Comment: I'm only being picky because that's how programming is too.  But `dd/MM/yyyy` doesn't match `16-03-2001` either.  One uses `/` and one uses `-`.  You need to be precise about stuff if you don't want it to go belly up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First that all you (we) should know how it is stored in the DB. To parse the "varchar date" to a datetime.

Let suppose we have the Date varchar storaged like mm/dd/yyyy
so You should use a `SELECT convert(datetime, THEDATECOLUMN, 101) -- mm/dd/yyyy`

You can take a look to more types of convert varchar to datetime [here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

Ok, in the understanding that you have to convert first the varchar to date time and in this example using the `mm/dd/yyyy` we should write the query like this way.

```
SELECT Id,Date,Name 
FROM people 
WHERE DATEPART(hh,convert(datetime, DATE, 101) ) >= 7 
AND DATEPART(hh,convert(datetime, DATE, 101) )  <= 8 
Order by convert(datetime, DATE, 101);
```

Depending of how it is storaged, you should change the type of conversion listed in the related link

Comment: Here's a convert resource that induces fewer seizures: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx :)

Comment: thanks.... it works.... one more thing how can I add these days to an array according to day ?

Comment: `convert(datetime, left(dt,10), 103) + convert(datetime, right(dt,8), 108)` will work for `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: i don;t know what are you trying for, but you can use also the Datepart to get the DAY, MONTH, YEAR, ETC, if you want the day  `DATEPART(dd,convert(datetime, DATE, 101) ) `

Comment: or what do you mean by "an array"?

Comment: @CoKoder this sounds like you might be best off posting a new question for this and explaining it carefully with some example code etc.